# Kotlin ViewModel onchange gets called multiple times when back from Fragment (using Lifecycle implementation)

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, fragment-oncreateview, lifecycleowner

I am working with the MVVM architecture.

### The code

When I click a button, the method **orderAction** is triggered. It just posts an enum (further logic will be added).

**ViewModel**

```
class DashboardUserViewModel(application: Application) : SessionViewModel(application) {

    enum class Action {
        QRCODE,
        ORDER,
        TOILETTE
    }

    val action: LiveData<Action>
        get() = mutableAction
    private val mutableAction = MutableLiveData<Action>()

    init {
    }

    fun orderAction() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            // Some queries before the postValue
            mutableAction.postValue(Action.QRCODE)    
        }
    }
}
```

The fragment observes the LiveData obj and calls a method that opens a new fragment. I'm using the navigator here, but I don't think that the details about it are useful in this context. Notice that I'm using **viewLifecycleOwner**

**Fragment**

```
class DashboardFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var binding: FragmentDashboardBinding
    private val viewModel: DashboardUserViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(DashboardUserViewModel::class.java)
    }

    private val observer = Observer<DashboardUserViewModel.Action> {
        // Tried but I would like to have a more elegant solution
        //if (viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
            it?.let {
                when (it) {
                    DashboardUserViewModel.Action.QRCODE -> navigateToQRScanner()
                    DashboardUserViewModel.Action.ORDER -> TODO()
                    DashboardUserViewModel.Action.TOILETTE -> TODO()
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentDashboardBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this

        viewModel.action.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)

        // Tried but still having the issue
        //viewModel.action.reObserve(viewLifecycleOwner, observer)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        // Tried but still having the issue
        //viewModel.action.removeObserver(observer)
    }

    private fun navigateToQRScanner() {
        log("START QR SCANNER")
        findNavController().navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.actionLoginToPrivacy())
    }
}
```

### The problem

When I close the opened fragment (using findNavController().navigateUp()), the Observe.onChanged of DashboardFragment is immediately called and the fragment is opened again.

I have already checked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48914311/viewmodel-onchange-gets-called-multiple-times-when-back-from-fragment) and tried all the proposed solutions in the [mentioned link](https://medium.com/@BladeCoder/architecture-components-pitfalls-part-1-9300dd969808) (as you can see in the commented code). Only [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57389316/1768336) worked, but it's not very elegant and forces me to do that check every time.

I would like to try a more solid and optimal solution.

Keep in mind that in that thread there was no Lifecycle implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how `LiveData` works, it's a value holder, it holds the last value.

If you need to have your objects consumed, so that the action only triggers once, consider wrapping your object in a `Consumable`, like this

```
class ConsumableValue<T>(private val data: T) {

    private val consumed = AtomicBoolean(false)

    fun consume(block: ConsumableValue<T>.(T) -> Unit) {
        if (!consumed.getAndSet(true)) {
            block(data)
        }
    }
}
```

then you define you LiveData as

```
val action: LiveData<ConsumableValue<Action>>
    get() = mutableAction
private val mutableAction = MutableLiveData<ConsumableValue<Action>>()
```

then in your observer, you'd do

```
private val observer = Observer<ConsumableValue<DashboardUserViewModel.Action>> {
        it?.consume { action ->
            when (action) {
                DashboardUserViewModel.Action.QRCODE -> navigateToQRScanner()
                DashboardUserViewModel.Action.ORDER -> TODO()
                DashboardUserViewModel.Action.TOILETTE -> TODO()
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! This solution is elegant, optimal, reusable and nerd. It's what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The issue happens because LiveData always post the available data to the observer if any data is readily available. Afterwords it will post the updates. I think it is the expected working since this behaviour has not been fixed even-though bug raised in issue tracker.
However there are many solutions suggested by developers in SO, i found this one easy to adapt and actually working just fine.

## Solution

```
viewModel.messagesLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        if (viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState == Lifecycle.State.RESUMED) {
            //Do your stuff
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE

Found a different and still useful implementation of what Frances answered [here](https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java). Take a look

Comment: This is what Google uses, so, i'd use that one (it's somewhat _unofficially_ known as the "SingleLiveData that doesn't trigger every time because liveData is only useful as a value holder for the UI and nothing else despite a lot of things supporting it for no reason" :)

Comment: Ye I started with the Francesc solution and then migrated to the Google one. But I will keep the Francesc solution as the offical answer since he drived me to this Google approach