# why flow collect call more than twice in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

Hey I am working in kotlin flow in android. I noticed that my kotlin flow `collectLatest` is calling twice and sometimes even more. I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67422183/11560810) but it didn't work for me. I printed the log inside my `collectLatest` function it print the log. I am adding the code

**MainActivity.kt**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CustomManager {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<ActivityViewModel>()
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private var time = 0

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        setupView()
    }

    private fun setupView() {
        viewModel.fetchData()

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                viewModel.conversationMutableStateFlow.collectLatest { data ->
                    Log.e("time", "${time++}")
                   ....
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**ActivityViewModel.kt**

```
class ActivityViewModel(app: Application) : AndroidViewModel(app) {

    var conversationMutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<ConversationDate>>(emptyList())

    fun fetchData() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val response = ApiInterface.create().getResponse()
            conversationMutableStateFlow.value = response.items
        }
    }

   .....
}
```

I don't understand why this is calling two times. I am attaching logs

```
2022-01-17 22:02:15.369 8248-8248/com.example.fragmentexample E/time: 0
2022-01-17 22:02:15.629 8248-8248/com.example.fragmentexample E/time: 1
```

As you can see it call two times. But I load more data than it call more than twice. I don't understand why it is calling more than once. Can someone please guide me what I am doing wrong. If you need whole code, I am adding my project [link](https://github.com/vivek-modi/FragmentExample).

Comment: I'm not expert here, but even name of `repeatOnLifecycle()` suggests that it calls the code block multiple times. And with each repetition you start another `collectLatest()`.

Comment: @broot what can i do this situation ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Android, but maybe remove this `repeatOnLifecycle()` and put `collectLatest()` directly inside `launchWhenStarted()`? Because this is what I think you need here: execute collection only once when started, not with each lifecycle change.

Comment: @broot I tried this already but it's not working :(

Comment: You have snipped out some code from collectLatest that might have to do with the problem. Can you add it back in?

Comment: @Tenfour04 sorry I didn't get it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using a [`MutableStateFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-mutable-state-flow/index.html) which derives from [`StateFlow`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/index.html), `StateFlow` has initial value, you are specifying it as an `emptyList`:

```
var conversationMutableStateFlow = MutableStateFlow<List<String>>(emptyList())
```

So the first time you get `data` in `collectLatest` block, it is an empty list. The second time it is a list from the response.

When you call `collectLatest` the `conversationMutableStateFlow` has only initial value, which is an empty list, that's why you are receiving it first.

You can change your `StateFlow` to [`SharedFlow`](http://%60SharedFlow%60), it doesn't have an initial value, so you will get only one call in `collectLatest` block. In `ActivityViewModel` class:

```
var conversationMutableStateFlow = MutableSharedFlow<List<String>>()

fun fetchData() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val response = ApiInterface.create().getResponse()
        conversationMutableStateFlow.emit(response.items)
    }
}
```

Or if you want to stick to `StateFlow` you can `filter` your data:

```
viewModel.conversationMutableStateFlow.filter { data ->
                data.isNotEmpty()
            }.collectLatest { data ->
                // ...
            }
```

Comment: thanks for explaning me. how can I remove `emptyList()`to call `collectLatest` only single time?

Comment: you can use `SharedFlow`, please see my edited answer.

Comment: can you guide me what is the proper way of sending first time data and initialise the fragment? Also what is the proper way of sending data more when fetchMoreData function called ?

Comment: this is my [class](https://github.com/vivek-modi/FragmentExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/fragmentexample/MainActivity.kt)

Comment: Please create another question here on Stackoverflow with complete description of your problem so others can also see it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for guiding me. I'll create another question.

Comment: can you look this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70755682/11560810)

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted
```

with

```
viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launch
```

Comment: Can you provide information to explain the difference?

Answer (score -1):

The reason is collectLatest like backpressure. If you pass multiple items at once, flow will collect latest only, but if there are some time between emits, flow will collect each like latest

EDITED:
You really need read about MVVM architecture.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    setupView()
}

private fun setupView() {
    if (supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentView) != null) 
        return
    
    supportFragmentManager
        .beginTransaction()
        .add(R.id.fragmentView, ConversationFragment())
        .commit()
}
}
```

Delele `ActivityViewModel` and add that logic to `FragmentViewModel`.
Also notice you don't need use `AndroidViewModel`, if you can use plain `ViewModel`. Use `AndroidViewModel` only when you need access to `Application` or its `Context`

Comment: What can I do ?

Comment: Why do you need to be called once only? For MVVM architecture is normal change UI because events and state from view model

Comment: Inside `collecLatest` I am creating a fragment and after that whenever I emit data I am passing the data in fragment. Can you please check this [file](https://github.com/vivek-modi/FragmentExample/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/fragmentexample/MainActivity.kt)

Comment: When `collectLatest` calling twice my if condition is getting true and same data is passing in my fragment.

Comment: Attaching fragment inside of collect is bad idea. Create view model for fragment, not activity

Comment: So your activity will contain fragment only. Fragment will be connected to view model and load, display data

Comment: can you please give me example ?